Family of graphs characterized by their eigenvalues
Studying the convergence/divergence of certain processes on simple graphs (processes similar to Kostant games on graphs), I'm confronted with the task of characterizing graphs whose spectra must satisfy the following property: Let say that the simple graph has $n$ vertices
$-2n+1 \le -\alpha +\beta\cdot \lambda \le 1, \forall \lambda \in Spec(A)$ where $A$ is the adjacency matrix of the graph
The special case $\alpha=\beta=1$ is known, thanks to a theorem of R. Smith. The graphs having all their eigenvalues $< 2$ is the well-known and ubiquitous family of simply laced Dynkin diagrams, also known as ADE graphs.
I would be glad to know if there are charaterizations for more general constrains like mine here above.
Thanks for any clues and glad to give more details you may need.
